# Why are my exceptions not being logged with ServiceStack NLog?

Tags: servicestack, nlog

Given this NLog config file:

```
<extensions>
  <add assembly="Seq.Client.NLog"/>
</extensions>

<variable name="ServiceName" value="LO.Leads.Processor"/>

<targets async="true">

  <target name="seq" xsi:type="Seq" serverUrl="http://mywebsite">
    <property name="ThreadId" value="${threadid}" as="number" />
    <property name="MachineName" value="${machinename}" />
  </target>

  <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
          layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${level}|${threadid}|${message}"
          fileName="C:\LogFiles\Leads\Processor\Processor.log" 
          archiveFileName="C:\LogFiles\Leads\Processor\Processor.{##}.log"
          archiveEvery="Day"
          archiveNumbering="Rolling"
          maxArchiveFiles="45"
          concurrentWrites="true"/>

  <target name="debugger" xsi:type="Debugger" 
          layout="${logger}:${message}"/>

  <target name="console" xsi:type="Console"           
          layout="${logger}:${level}:${threadid}:${message}" />

</targets>

<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="seq" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="file" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="debugger" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />
</rules>
```

and this code block:

```
public class Program
{
    static Program()
    {
        LogManager.LogFactory = new NLogFactory();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {               
        HostFactory.Run(x =>
        {
            x.Service<ProcessorAppHost>(s =>
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(name => new ProcessorAppHost());
                s.WhenStarted(ah =>
                {
                    ah.Init();
                    ah.Start("http://*:8088/");
                    "Message processor listening at http://localhost:8088 ".Print();
                });
                s.WhenStopped(ah => ah.Dispose());
            });
            x.RunAsLocalSystem();

            x.SetDescription("Processes all messages for the Leads application.");
            x.SetDisplayName("Leads Message Processor");
            x.SetServiceName("LOLeadsProcessor");
        });
    }
}



//MQHandlers
mqServer.RegisterHandler<LeadInformation>(m =>
{
    try
    {
        var db = container.Resolve<IFrontEndRepository>();
        db.SaveMessage(m as Message);    
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        _log.Error("This is the only text logged", exception);                   
    }

    return ServiceController.ExecuteMessage(m);
});
```

and this exception

[image: Exception being logged]

and here is the output from the 'file' logger

2014-11-11 10:06:53.9179|ProcessorAppHost|Error|24|This is the only text logged

Any idea about how to get the overloaded version of Error to work correctly?

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${message}` contains the message of your exception, which is "This is the only text logged".

Take a look at the [exception layout renderer](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer).

```
layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${level}|${threadid}|${message}|${exception}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you told ServiceStack to use NLog anywhere? e.g. before initializing your AppHost:

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new ServiceStack.Logging.NLogger.NLogFactory();
new AppHost().Init();
```

Comment: Updated my question, but yes, the logger is configured prior to init. It is logging, but the overloaded version does not log the exception details to the target

Comment: @Stephen ok if it's logging than it must be a NLog speicifc config issue. ServiceStack's NLog is just a proxy to the underlying [NLog Logger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Logging.NLog/NLogLogger.cs).